# Matrix Inequality Determinant Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to bound the determinant of the following matrix from below:

$$|D+(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})|.$$

Where $D$ is a pd matrix, $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ , $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times qr}$ ,$\mathcal{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{qr\times r}$ and $C_{[X]}$ is the projection matrix to the space orthogonal to the column space of $X$.
There is a paper I am reading and I am trying to determine how they derived the bound.
$$|D+(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})|>|D+Y^TC_{[X,Z]}Y|.$$ Since $C(X)\subset C([X,Z])$ where $C(Z)$ is the column space of Z, then $C([X,Z])^{+}\subset C(X)^{+}$ this implies $\lambda_i(C_{[X,Z]})\le \lambda_i(C_{[X]})$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i^{th}$ ordered eigenvalue .This implies

$$C_{[X,Z]} \le C_{[X]}. $$

Consider

$$|D+(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})|=|D||I + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}|.$$

Since $D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is symmetric it is diagonalizable and since its psd then $\lambda_i(D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}})\ge 0$.  Note that $$D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ge D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X,Z]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
then,

$$|D||I + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\ge |D||I + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X,Z]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})D^{-\frac{1}{2}}|.$$

This implies

$$|D+(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})|\ge |D+(Y-Z\mathcal{A})^TC_{[X,Z]}(Y-Z\mathcal{A})|=|D+Y^TC_{[X,Z]}Y|.$$

Where the last equality follows from orthogonality. Does my work hold? Are there any oversights?

Comment: Is the bound supposed to hold for all $Y$? Which paper is this from?